# CocoaPods ~> (Optimistic operator) downloading something else

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, cocoapods

I had two separate CocoaPods, they're named like this,

4.3.1-test

4.3.1-testBeta

Then I created a third one and named it,

4.3.1-testX

When users users write the podfile like this:
pod 'Podname', '~>4.3.1-test'

It ends up downloading '4.3.1-testX'

Why is this happening? Is it because I pushed '4.3.1-testX' after '4.3.1-test'?

How to solve this? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer to my own question,

The optimistic operator (~>) does not care about the string in the version name (x.y.z-string).

Therefore, even if the strings are different, it will download the most recently pushed pod.